# How to use Matplotlib PLOT.in file to include legend in plot (produced by VASPKIT) / Plotting a .dat file using MPL?

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I'm currently using VASPKIT to plot a .dat file. Example below:

```
| #Energy    XX(cm^-1)       YY(cm^-1)      ZZ(cm^-1)       XY(cm^-1)       YZ(cm^-1)       XZ(cm^-1)
  0.0000  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.0312  6.22767265E-01  7.10173058E-01  4.86725751E-01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.0625  2.49494263E+00  2.84511004E+00  1.94994910E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.0937  5.61018281E+00  6.39747830E+00  4.38471308E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.1249  9.96973466E+00  1.13686476E+01  7.79222725E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.1561  1.55727513E+01  1.77575895E+01  1.21717910E+01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.1874  2.29641298E+01  2.55762097E+01  1.75318755E+01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.2186  3.11407524E+01  3.47979899E+01  2.38546750E+01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.2498  4.05570539E+01  4.54316549E+01  3.11470776E+01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.2810  5.12100332E+01  5.74753421E+01  3.94065748E+01  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00

The documentation asks me to edit the PLOT.in file to change plot output. I have written the below:
# Legend-related settings     =
show_legend                   =     .TRUE.                         # .TRUE. or .FALSE (default: .TRUE.).
legend_location               =     'upper right'                  # string type (default: 'best'). Options: 'best', 'upper right', 'upper left', 'lower left', 'lower right', 'right', 'center left', 'center right', 'lower center', 'upper center', 'center',
legend_fontsize               =      12.0                          # float type (default: 14.0).
legend_label                  =      'hello'
legend_title                = 'hello'
```

But, no legend is shown in the jpg output:

[image]

I do not know how to change it so that I can get a legend in the top right corner.

---

I tried adding legend_label and legend_title (the rest was already there). Any help is very much appreciated! :)

I'm not sure how the inner code of vaspkit works, even though it is based in python.

I would like to be able to plot the dat file on my own but do not know how to do that without it being in pandas or csv format.